# How do I avoid saving duplicate records when saving objects with many to many relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, duplicates, many-to-many

I'm trying to wrap my mind around this but I could really use some pointers.

Currently I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities and my application is working fine. However, I'd like to modify how my data gets stored regarding the tags table. I would like for only unique tags to be stored in the tags table.

**Posts.cs:**

```
public class Post : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }   // many
}
```

**Tags.cs:**

```
public class Tag : IEntity
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }   // many    
}
```

Entity Framework has created 3 tables, one for each class and one navigation table which look like this. As you can see I'm currently storing duplicate copies of the same tag name.

[image]

### How do I avoid saving duplicate records like this?

My intuition was to start at my PostController action where I receive my form data via HttpPost.

**PostController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,URL,IntroText,Body,Created,Modified,Author,Tags")] Post post)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (UnitOfWork uwork = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var newPost = new Post
            {
                Title = post.Title,
                URL = post.URL,
                IntroText = post.IntroText,
                Body = replace,
                Author = post.Author,
                //Tags = post.Tags 
            };

           // check for duplicate entries
           foreach (var tag in post.Tags) 
           {         
               var tagCount = uwork.TagRepository.GetAll().Where(s => s.Name.Equals(tag.Name)).Count();

                if (tagCount < 1) {
                    // not sure if I'm on the right track
                }
            }
            uwork.PostRepository.Insert(newPost);
            uwork.Commit();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
```

Once I began on this route I started to second guess this because I realized that if I conditionally omit duplicates here the post will just lose the tag reference altogether. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you are on the right track. If tag names are unique theres no need to "Count" though. Just get the first one if it exists. Swap out dupes and do nothing for uniques

```
// check for duplicate entries
foreach (var tag in post.Tags.ToList()) 
{         
    var dupeTag = uwork.TagRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == tag.Name);

    //Replace tag with the dupe if found
    if(dupeTag != null)
    {
        post.Tags.Remove(tag);
        post.Tags.Add(dupeTag);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I pull an existing tag record from the database, I just simply throw away the incoming reference and Add() the tag to the existing record? (Going to try this now)

Comment: I thought it was going to be so complicated, this makes so much sense now. Thanks Shoe! This is awesome.